# Add _redirects file to root path for Vue SPA hosted on Netlify

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vue-cli, netlify

I'm developing a Single Page App using Vue CLI and want history pushstate to work so I get clean URLs.

I have to follow this: https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps and add a `_redirects` file to the root of my site folder with the following:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

The problem is I don't know how to add this `_redirects` file to the root of my dist folder. I tried adding it to the static folder but it ends up in a subfolder and not in root. How can I include this file so that history mode works after deploying on Netlify ?

```
// config/index.js
build: {
  // Paths
  assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
  assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
  assetsPublicPath: '/',
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### vue-cli created app 3.x

For the new build setup using the vue-cli version 3.0.0-beta.x there is a public folder now and you do not need the following setup. Just put your `_redirects` file under the `public` folder root. When you build it will make a copy to the dist folder which will be used for your deploy.

### vue-cli created app prior to 3.x

Vue.js uses webpack to copy the static assets. This is maintained in `webpack.prod.conf.js` for the production build which is what you will need in this case for Netlify. I believe the best and cleanest configuration is [based on this solution.](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/657)

Search the file for the `new CopyWebpackPlugin` in `webpack.prod.conf.js`.

```js
// copy custom static assets
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
    to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
    ignore: ['.*']
  }
])
```

**Create a root ( folder in your project same level of the static folder )**
You could name this anything you like, but I will use `root` for the example.

You would then make sure the `_redirects` file is in the new `root` directory or whatever you called it. In this case it is named `root`

Now modify the `webpack.prod.conf.js` CopyWebpackPlugin section to look like the following:

```js
// copy custom static assets
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
    to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
    ignore: ['.*']
  },
  {
    from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../root'),
    to: config.build.assetsRoot,
    ignore: ['.*']
  }
])
```

Comment: Yes I have tried placing the `_redirects` file in the static folder but it is then placed in the static folder in dist folder whereas I need to have `_redirects` at root after build so that Netlify picks it up

Comment: Right, but did you check your setting like mentioned in the answer above?

Comment: Yes I have the same settings as above (edited in my question), I'm trying to avoid changing the SubDirectory to empty string so that the `_redirects` file ends in the root of the public folder as I only need it for this file

Comment: I see your problem now. sorry, see my edits based on your requirements

Comment: Your new answer is spot on ! Thank you very much. I'm sure it will be useful to other people who are hosting a Single Page App on Netlify

Comment: It should help anyone using vue.js for sure and Netlfy

Comment: The webpack configuration is all different in vue-cli version 3. How would we do the equivalent configuration in that setup?

Comment: For the new build setup using the vue-cli version 3.0.0-beta.x there is a public folder now and you do not need this setup. Just put your `_redirects` file under the `public` folder root. When you build it will make a copy to the dist folder which will be used for your deploy.

Comment: Awesome thanks! You should add that to your answer, very useful!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, even that I'm using React.js 16 :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this @talves - was driving me crazy that `_redirects` did not get served correctly

Answer (score 21):

You could also just use the `netlify.toml` file which tends to be a bit cleaner. Just put this in the file to get the redirect you were looking for:

```
# The following redirect is intended for use with most SPA's that handles routing internally.
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

`netlify.toml` is normally stored in the root of your site repository.

You can find more info about this file [here](https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/).

Comment: this will broke the form functionality

Comment: just remove this line `force = true # Ensure that we always redirect` and add the history mode other then that this code is working file in my view js project

Comment: Don't use force = true, because then all your other assets (including all your javascript code) also get redirected to index.html !

Answer (score 12):

I've tried Rutger Willems's snippet without the last line and it works.  Credit goes to Hamish Moffatt.

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

Answer (score 9):

Just in case you're looking for an answer on Nuxt instead of Vue, add the _redirects file to the static/ directory.

Comment: the answer is not relevant to the question

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add the _redirects file to your /public directory in your vue app

Answer (score 1):

For vue3(should work on vue2 as well). Combining answers from the above and from the netlify website.
The solution which worked for me, is using `netlify.toml` file

1. Create a `netlify.toml` file with the below content.

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

2. Put it inside `public` folder. This should be in root directory.
3. This will be copied to the `dist` folder in production.