# Why is my _redirects file not being recognized?

Tags: vue.js, github, vue-router, netlify

I am using npm to build my VueJS project. After the project is done building a "dist" folder is created. I have a _redirects file in my dist folder, but every time I deploy my project on netlify it always says

> No redirect rules processed. This deploy did not include any redirect rules.

Does anyone know why my _redirects file is not being recognized?

Comment: Going to need to see some code in order to help...

Comment: Thanks for commenting but I have found the solution! @MattOestreich

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found was from the link below. Just put the _redirects file inside of the public folder even though dist is the folder being deployed.

[Add _redirects file to root path for Vue SPA hosted on Netlify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729023/add-redirects-file-to-root-path-for-vue-spa-hosted-on-netlify)